# the php code dose not go to error function , this function goes directly in handle_data(); function

Tags: php

why php code does not go in show error or check_data function

```
<?php
$error_array = array();
if (isset($_REQUEST["welcome_already_seen"])) {
    check_data();
    if (count($error_array) != 0) {
        show_error();
        show_welcome();
    } else {
        handle_data();
    }
} else {
    show_welcome();
}

function show_welcome()
{
    echo "<form method='post'>
        <input type='text' name='flavor'>
        <input type='submit' value='submit'>
        <input type='hidden' name='welcome_already_seen' value='already_seen'>
        </form>";
}

function check_data()
{
    if ($_REQUEST["flavor"] == "") {
        $error_array[] = "<div style='color:red'>please enter flavor</div>";
    }
}

function show_error()
{
    global $error_array;
    foreach ($error_array as $err) {
        echo $err, "<br>";
    }
}

function handle_data()
{
    echo "flavor =";
    echo $_REQUEST["flavor"];
}

?>
```

why php code does not go in show error or check_data function
is there any solution
and tell what the problem within the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed `global $error_array` in your function `check_data`. It is going to `check_data()` but setting a local variable so the global `$error_array` is always empty.

```
 function check_data(){     
    global $error_array;
    if($_REQUEST["flavor"] == ""){          
        $error_array[] = "<div style='color:red'>please enter flavor</div>";
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

It does go to `check_data` function but you are using `$error_array` in local scope hence global array is not populated.

You should make it global in your function - like that:

```
    function check_data(){
        global $error_array;

        if($_REQUEST["flavor"] == ""){
            $error_array[] = "<div style='color:red'>please enter flavor</div>";
        }
    }
```